# Max formula returning 0 based on values from another formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested, max

I am trying to make the following work:

```
A               B   C   D       
BK-8811436091   57  1   Unique      
BK-8811436091   57  1   Duplicate       
BK-8811436091   57  1   Duplicate       
BK-8811436091   58  1   Unique      
BK-8811436091   57  1   Duplicate       
BK-8811436091   59  1   Unique      
BK-8811436091   57  1   Duplicate       
BK-8811436091   58  1   Duplicate       
BK-8811436092   54  1   Unique      
BK-8811436092   56  1   Unique      
BK-8811436092   58  1   Unique      
BK-8811436092   57  1   Unique      
BK-8811436091   57  1   Duplicate       
BK-8811436091   58  1   Duplicate       
BK-8811436092   57  1   Duplicate
```

- If column A+B have a unique combination it should give 1 in column C
- If column A+B have a duplicate it should receive the same number as it did before (e.g. row 2 should be 1 in column C)
- if column A is equal but column B is different, the number in column C should get + 1 (e.g. row 4 should be 2 in column C and consequently a 3 in row 6)
- if there is an entirely unique column A+B this should get a 1 again (e.g. row 9 should get a 1).

I have been attempting this with the following formula in column C (which gives wrong answers right now):

```
=IF(AND(D2="unique";A2&B2<>A1&B1);B2-B2+1;IF(AND(D2="Duplicate";A2&B2=A1&B1);MAX(IF($A$2:A2=A2;$C$2:C2));IF(AND(A2&B2<>A1&B1;D2="unique");MAX(IF($A$2:A2=A2;$C$2:C2)+1);MAX(IF($A$2:A2=A2;$C$2:C2)))))
```

I don't think it's entirely correct yet but I feel I should be able to manage it with this train of thought. One of the problems that are occuring is that the max formula is returning 0 values even though there are quite obviously 1's in column C --> max returning 1 + 1 should lead to two.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I am no programmer / coder so please correct me if my formatting of this question is wrong.

Kind regards,

VHes

Comment: What Excel version are you using? And can you post an example of what you would expect - to me your conditions are not clear ... are C and D the result of formulas? or only the values in C?

Comment: Are you doing this to use it for something else? What's the end goal of this counter?

Comment: @Ike

I will post an example tomorrow! I am using Excel 2021 (office 2021)

Comment: @p.b

It is work related stuff. Sadly I cannot post the relevant database due to privacy issues :(

Comment: I don't ask for that. I think the counter is there to be used for a next step. Creating a list of of uniques only, or sorting by uniques in A, or I don't know what. Maybe it's harder to reach the step you're now asking than reaching to the end goal directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Result]

This is my approach to find duplicates & unique values., based on your excel versions you can choose the formulas & If you have large set of data, **CountIf** is not the best option. Instead, use Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:A1=A1)*($D$1:D1="Unique"))`
In `C1` dragged down.

[image]